# Having ejs error SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list in C:\Users\computer point\Desktop\project2\views\home.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I am trying to get data from app.js through ejs but its giving an error.

computerSci Student

```
<%- include('header'); -%>
<h1><%= foo%></h1>
<p class = "home-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<% for(var i = 0 ;i< posts.length;i++)%>
<%console.log(posts[i].title);%>// THIS LINE GIVES AN ERROR AND I AM UNANBLE TO POST THIS ON HOME.EJS
<%}%>

<%- include('footer'); -%>
```

I Believe someone help me to remove this error

Comment: Why are you inserting a `console.log()` into the rendering of your template?  That does not seem appropriate.Also, please show to code that prepares the data that you pass to the template and show the code that calls `res.render()` and passes the data so we can see exactly what you're passing into the template?  And, what is `<%}%>` supposed to be?

Comment: app.post('/compose',function(req,res){
  newData = req.body.title;

  var post = [{
   match : req.body.title,
    post : req.body.post
  }]

posts.push(post);
res.redirect("/");
});
app.get('/compose',function(req,res){
res.render('compose');
})

Comment: if we remove console.log it also gives an error

Comment: multiline code in comments is not readable. Please use the edit link to add the code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use data inside your template, you have to pass data to `res.render()`.  The format for `res.render()` is this:

```
res.render(view [, locals] [, callback])
```

Where the second argument `locals` is the data you want passed to your template.  I can't tell exactly from your question what you're trying to do or which template is which, but it looks like you could do something this:

```
app.post('/compose',function(req,res){ 
    let posts = [{ title : req.body.title, post : req.body.post }];
    res.render("compose", posts);
});
```

And, change your compose template to this:

```
<%- include('header'); -%>
<p class = "home-content">It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>
<ul>
<% posts.forEach(function(post) { %>
    <li><%= post.title %></li>
<%})%>
</ul>

<%- include('footer'); -%>
```